# What is the best way in terms of space efficiency to make a List of objects immutable?

Tags: java, list, collections

Prompted by the example provided at [37:19 of this talk by Stuart Marks on Java Collections](https://youtu.be/ogRVWXuuAU4?t=2239), I was wondering what is the best way to make a List of objects immutable from a space efficiency perspective.

In my example, I have a List of objects that I retrieve from a database:

`List<MyObject> myObjects = myRepository.getMyObjectsThatFitCriteria();`

To make this List immutable I can think of three ways to do it

1. Wrap it in `Collections.unModifiableList()` but this creates another object and the underlying list itself is still modifiable
2. Stream over the `myObjects` list and collect it to an unmodifiable list but this might have a performance impact, particularly if the list is large
3. Use the `List.copyOf()` static factory method introduced in Java 9 but this creates another copy of the `myObjects` list, impacting memory and storage.

Comment: Collections.unmodifiableList creates a lightweight wrapper which is inconsequential.  And the original List won’t be modified by the repository, so unless your own code plans to modify it, it will never be modified.  List.copyOf is the same.  Remember that a new List does not create new objects, only references to the same elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @VGR in the comment, `Collections.unmodifiableList` will not copy the elements into a new list, but rather wrap it and prevent modifications on it.

If you're using Spring Data JPA for repository support, it's a good idea to leverage its support for streams: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-java-8

Streams are a good way to avoid large memory consumption if the list is large. It does not change the source collection and allows lazy consumption.

Answer (score 0):

> Wrap it in Collections.unModifiableList() but this creates another object and the underlying list itself is still modifiable.

You still need to create a list so there is no way around that.  But you can always reassign to the same list to effectively remove the reference from access.

```
list = Collections.unModifiableList(list);
```

The original list internally is simply referred to (thus not copied) for immutable methods like `size()`.  Any other methods that would allow changes are overridden with methods that throw exceptions if they are invoked.  So the overhead is minimal.

Note that unless the contained objects are immutable, they are still subject to alteration.